# I am trying to make a rectangle which takes a user inut to get a size

Tags: java, graphics

I am new to java and I  want to make a rectangle which uses a user input with scanner to get a size for the rectangle. The problem is that it takes the user inputs but it doesn't display the rectangle. I believe it is because my y integer is in a static function, but I am not sure how to fix this. I searched google for quite a long time but I couldn't find an answer. Could anyone please help me? Thank you. :)

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.*;

    public class Shape extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

        Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);

        public static void main(String[] args){
             System.out.println("Place in the width of your vaccum cleaner here:");     
             Scanner myY = new Scanner(System.in);
             int y = myY.nextInt();

             JFrame jf = new JFrame("Title");
             jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
             Shape s = new Shape();
             jf.add(s);
             jf.setSize(600, 400);
             jf.setVisible(true);
        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
             super.paintComponent(g);
             this.setBackground(Color.PINK);

             g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
             g.fillRect(0, 0, 40, y);

             tm.start();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't compile, so there is now way it will show the rectangle. 
`int y` is defined in `main`, and it is not recognized in `paintComponent`.

make it a class variable : `static int y;`  and initialize it in `main` by : `y = myY.nextInt();`

Comment: Thanks, appreciated.